# best practice puppeteer waitForSelector or setTimeout

Tags: javascript, checkbox, puppeteer

I try to find the best way to "wait until the complete website is loaded". And this seems to be a tricky thing. I was googleing alot and saw that there are 2 ways: waitForSelector and SetTimout.

My problem is, even if I wait for the Selector #CheckSelectAll to check this Checkbox it seems it's always too early. So I had to add a delay of 2 seconds. And this looks very unprofessional for me. I want to use the best practice for this.

This should be an issue everybody always needs when using puppeteer with different pages and forms.

Is it possible that this waitForSelector doesn't work when the selector is inside an iFrame?

Thanks for any advice and help!

```
  function delay(time) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve) { 
        setTimeout(resolve, time)
    });

  await page.waitForSelector('#CheckSelectAll');
  await delay(2000);
  await page.click('#CheckSelectAll');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to make it real "puppeteer" way, take a look at [this](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagewaitfornavigationoptions).
There is a few options to choose, but in my practice I found the most useful `networkidle2`.

As said in documentation, your script will wait until

> there are no more than 2 network connections for at least 500 ms.

```
await page.waitForNavigation({ waitUntil: 'networkidle2' })
```

But, if for some reason in-box solution can't handle your case, it's O.K. to make custom wait function as you did.
Here is nice one line, to write less code:
`await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 2000))`

And the last one option, you can access DOM with [`page.evaluate()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageevaluatepagefunction-args) and verify if element is visible.

```
const visibleVerification = await page.evaluate(() => { 
   // your verify logic.
   // return boolean, if element exists on page
   return true;
})
```